# PHP PDO MySQL how to select all values from a particular column and read into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, tree

I am looking to build a tree from provided data in the form id, name, parent_id, for it to be useful I am looking at changing the direction of the tree to make things easier to iterate through (note: I don't have to then store the info again).

So far I have got

```
$SQL = "SELECT id, name, parent_id WHERE parent_id = '$parent'";
[execution code]
```

And I want it to read something like

```
$tree[<id of parent for tree root, id of children>]['children'] = 
                             array($results[all rows]['id']);
```

But I have no idea how to go about this I keep reading parts of arrays into the array so I end up with nested arrays which obviously messes up my code,

Comment: Can you post some of the code you had already tried and an example of the resulting array?

Comment: You're using the "adjacency-list" model of representing hierarchical data, which requires recursion to manipulate or access arbitrary levels. Unfortunately, MySQL (unlike some other RDBMS) does not support recursive functions, so it is not well-suited to this model. You might consider restructuring your database to use the "nested sets" or "transitive closure table" models instead. [@Bill Karwin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20860) introduces them nicely in his presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Comment: is it possible to have level > 1 , so is it possible to have child of child ?

Comment: yes grandchildren are possible, code I've tried has been and gone...sorry I don't really save versions unless it works, as for changing the structure of the data, I am supplied my data from an upstream company so it's not possible to change it really without first doing this

Comment: This is the current output that I am working with vs the code I am using for the function http://pastebin.com/rqtr9n3N